# In Akka, when a message is sent to an Actor Pool, does 'self' hold a reference to the Actor instance or to the entire Pool?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

What is the behavior if I send a message to an Actor pool whose Actors then, upon receiving that message, send a message to `self`?  In this case, is sending to `self` going to send messages to the pool, or to the specific Actor instance that sent the message?

Pseudocode of this scenario would look like the following

```
...
val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
val actorPool: ActorRef = system.actorOf(
  Props(new SomeActor(someDependency))
    .withRouter(RoundRobinPool(conf.someActorPoolSize))
actorPool ! "hello"

class SomeActor(someDependency: SomeDependency) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case hello @ "hello" => self ! hello + " world"
    // ^Does the above send to the entire Pool, or does this specific
    // Actor just send the message directly to itself?
    case msg @ "hello world" => println(msg)
    // ^Do I know that the same Actor insntance that sent me "hello world"
    // is also going to execute "println(msg)", or could any Actor in the
    // Pool have sent the "hello world" message?
  }
}
```

Comment: Assume in the above code that `SomeActor` is the only type of Actor in the system.  This helps clarify what the last code comment is asking.  Ignore the fact that `someDependency` is never used - it's only there to more accurately reflect the actual code I have in my real application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`self`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/Actor.html#self:akka.actor.ActorRef) always points to an actor's own `ActorRef`:

```
def receive = {
  case hello @ "hello" =>
    self ! hello + " world" // sends "hello world" to itself
  case msg @ "hello world" =>
    println(msg)
```

When the routee sends `"hello world"` to `self`, it's sending that string to itself. This `"hello world"` string will then be captured in the `case msg @ "hello world" =>` clause, and the actor will print the message.

> Do I know that the same Actor insntance that sent me "hello world"
>   is also going to execute "println(msg)"...

An external actor could send either `"hello"` or `"hello world"` to the router. The router would then *forward* the message to one of the routees. For a routee to determine whether a `"hello world"` message was from itself or an external actor, the routee would have to inspect the value of `sender` (e.g., it could check whether `sender` was equal to `self`).

> ...or could any Actor in the Pool have sent the "hello world" message?

It's unclear what you're asking here. Routees typically don't communicate with each other.

> How would I send a message back to the Pool, instead of to 'self'? Would I need to pass the reference to the Actor Pool as a dependency, even though my Actor is a member of the Pool it wants to send messages to?

A routee doesn't need to know about other routees or the router. If you want to send a message back to the pool, let the original sender (i.e., the actor that sent the message to the *router*) do this. In other words, have your routee send the message to `sender`, and let that actor send the message back to the router. To emphasize this point, `sender` in this context is *not* the router/pool, but the original sender (there are a few exceptions to this, as described in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/routing.html#router-special-messages)):

```
client            --> router --> [routee1, routee2, etc.]
(original sender)                // sender in a routee is a reference to client, because
                                 // the router forwards the messages to the routees
```

You can read more about routing [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/routing.html).

Comment: How would I send a message back to the Pool, instead of to 'self'?  Would I need to pass the reference to the Actor Pool as a dependency, even though my Actor is a member of the Pool it wants to send messages to?

Comment: Assume `SomeActor` is the only thing which sends `"hello world"` messages, so we can guarantee that a `"hello world"` comes from a `SomeActor`.

Comment: To send a message back to the Pool from one of the router actors try: sender() ! msg // send msg back to the Pool

Comment: @josiah: Updated.

Comment: @richj: That's incorrect. `sender` in a routee is a reference to the original sender, not the router. This is because a router _forwards_ messages to its routees.

Comment: @chunjef - Thanks. I should have said context.parent (as explained in the Senders section of the documentation) to send a message back to the router/pool. This might be useful for messages related to supervision, where the original sender doesn't need to be involved.